# How to use find_package after add_subdirectory

Tags: cmake

I am trying to import a third party package into my project. So I've been following:

- https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/install/installing.html

But this fails with:

```
/tmp/top-level/bin/extern/MyLib
CMake Error at bin/extern/MyLib/MyLibConfig.cmake:12 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /tmp/top-level/bin/extern/MyLib/MyLibTargets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
```

What am I missing from the documentation ? For reference, my top level cmakelists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(top-level)

add_subdirectory(extern)
find_package(MyLib CONFIG REQUIRED HINTS
             ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/extern/MyLib)
```

And the cmakelists.txt file for 'MyLib' is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(MyLib VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES C)

add_library(MyLib mylib.c)
add_library(MyLib::MyLib ALIAS MyLib)

install(
  TARGETS MyLib
  EXPORT MyLibTargets
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  INCLUDES
  DESTINATION include)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(
  MyLibConfigVersion.cmake
  VERSION ${PACKAGE_VERSION}
  COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion)

install(
  EXPORT MyLibTargets
  FILE MyLibTargets.cmake
  NAMESPACE MyLib::
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/MyLib)

configure_file(MyLibConfig.cmake.in MyLibConfig.cmake @ONLY)
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibConfig.cmake"
              "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibConfigVersion.cmake"
        DESTINATION lib/cmake/MyLib)
```

Comment: CMake project cannot use a config file (via `find_package`), which is created with `install(EXPORT)` in the **same project**. That config file is usable only after **installing** the project (e.g. with `make install`). The target ``MyLib::MyLib`` is already accessible for your main `CMakeLists.txt`, just use it. If you are not allowed to drop `find_package(MyLib)` call, then you could prepare "fake" config file, which does nothing (since all targets are already accessible).

Comment: @Tsyvarev could you post this comment as answer. I fail to understand (based on your comment above) why [this](https://github.com/malaterre/PublicRep/blob/master/CMake/test6/CMakeLists.txt) works then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory:

You use script `MyLibConfig.cmake` from the **build** directory, and this script attempts to load the script `MyLibTargets.cmake` created by `install(EXPORT MyLibTargets)`.

But the latter script is intended to work only after the project will be **installed**, it cannot work while the project is being *built*.

Actually, the whole call `find_package(MyLib)` is not needed in that situation:
since current project builds `MyLib`, the target `MyLib::MyLib` is already accessible for you.

---

If you want to make your top-level project to be flexible, so it would work both in cases `MyLib` is already installed or just being built, then you could use `find_package` *conditionally*:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(top-level)

# This project could be built as standalone.
# In that case 'MyLib' is assumed to be already installed.
#
# Also, this project could work as a subproject of some other project,
# which also builds `MyLib` via 'add_subdirectory(MyLib)'.

if(NOT TARGET MyLib::MyLib)
    find_package(MyLib CONFIG REQUIRED)
endif()

# ... use MyLib via 'MyLib::MyLib' target.
```

---

Alternatively, you may write `MyLibConfig.cmake` script in a manner, which allows it to be used even if `MyLib` is currently being built.

```
if(TARGET MyLib::MyLib)
  return()
endif()

# ... usual content of the config file.
```

In that case, `CMakeLists.txt` for the root project could be simplified:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(top-level)

# Normal use case is that 'MyLib' is already installed.
# But the project could work as a subproject in other scenarios.
#
# In those scenarios, a parent project should care about
# 'find_package' to work.
find_package(MyLib CONFIG REQUIRED)

# ... use MyLib via 'MyLib::MyLib' target.
```

The usage of the project in case of 'MyLib' being built could be as follows:

```
- CMakeLists.txt (outer)
- MyLib
  - CMakeLists.txt (MyLib)
- top_level
  - CMakeLists.txt ("top-level")
```

Outer `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(outer)

add_subdirectory(MyLib)

# Help inner project to find config file for MyLib.
#
# Here we use *internal* knowledge of MyLib project,
# that it generates 'MyLibConfig.cmake' directly in its build directory.
#
# Note: find_package expects 'XXX_DIR' variable to be CACHE one.
set(MyLib_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLib"
  CACHE INTERNAL "Directory with MyLibConfig.cmake"
)

add_subdirectory(top_level)
```